# Android resize one part of layout when soft keyboard displayed

Tags: android, android-layout, keyboard

I want to create layout which consists in normal condition from image and few EditTexts as displayed in the next image
[image: Before editing]

But when user starts to enter the text I need to change the layout the next way:
Soft keyboard at the bottom of screen,
EditTexts about it but Image is resized according to the size of soft keyboard as displayed here
[image: After the keyboard]
How can I do it? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: put them in a ScrollView and make sure in the Manifest you add "adjustResize" for the corresponding activity.

Comment: But I dont need scroll, I need layout which fits the entire screen

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Also set

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

as property to your Activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`